# Secugen using c++

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

Good day everyone. I am using Secugen fingerprint scanner, and when I compile it on c++ it gives me an error saying "undefined reference to SGFPM_Create":

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include </home/pi/Documents/list/sgfplib.h>

HSGFPM m_hFPM;
DWORD err = SGFPM_Create(&m_hFPM);
```

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: is it DWORD err = SGFPM_Create(&m_hFPM) ??

Comment: Sorry typo. but yes it is a DWORD err...

Comment: Did you add its lib to linker?

Comment: @idris I dont know how to do that. Im using Geany(on Rasp Pi) as my IDE.

Comment: you need to add the particular library

Comment: @Som I apologize for being spoonfeeded. but can you teach me how to do it?

Comment: @frange https://wiki.geany.org/_media/howtos/images/project-properties.png. add secugen library to link field.

Comment: @idris [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rW8L9Dp34Lf3W58pvXTvYLdqwah3Znjz/view?usp=sharing)
Thank you. Did it but still get the same error.

Comment: You should learn secugen library file name. Than add it at the end of linker g++ command -lSECUGENLIBNAME.

Comment: I try to compile it with and it success. but when i try to build it I got the same error message
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rW8L9Dp34Lf3W58pvXTvYLdqwah3Znjz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you try add it to Build section.